# asp.net Download files from protected server

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have searched various forums and links but havn't got anything helpful yet.

Actually i working towards developing a web application in ASP.net using C# that enables use to login on a remote server and then download files from that server.

Curently i m able to login to that server and see the content of the protected page.

But when it comes to download the file, i get an Unauthorize access error.

I m able to download images from the server but those are not protected.

the code i have developed so far is

```
    protected void Unnamed1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {

        string LOGIN_URL = "https://some.server/";

        // first, request the login form to get the value

        HttpWebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(LOGIN_URL) as HttpWebRequest;
        webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        webRequest.KeepAlive = true;
        webRequest.UserAgent = userAgent;
        String received = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Request.BinaryRead(Request.ContentLength));
        webRequest.ContentLength = received.Length;
        webRequest.Proxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("usrname", "password", "domain");
        StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream(), Encoding.ASCII);
        string responseData = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
        responseReader.Close();
        string postData = "user=usr&password=pass&switch=Login";
        Response.Write(webRequest.Address);

        // have a cookie container ready to receive the forms auth cookie

        CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();

        // now post to the login form

        webRequest = WebRequest.Create(LOGIN_URL) as HttpWebRequest;
        webRequest.Method = "POST";
        webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        webRequest.CookieContainer = cookies;

        // write the form values into the request message

        StreamWriter requestWriter = new StreamWriter(webRequest.GetRequestStream());
        requestWriter.Write(postData);
        requestWriter.Close();

        // we don't need the contents of the response, just the cookie it issues 

        webRequest.GetResponse().Close();



        // Download files

        WebProxy myProxy = new WebProxy("server.https.com", 443);
        //WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://some.server/file.zip");
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://some.server/file.zip");
        request.Proxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("usrname", "password", "domain");

        string filename = "file.zip";
        string filepath = "C:\\Documents and Settings\\user\\Desktop\\" + filename.ToString();

        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("usrname", "password", "domain");
        client.DownloadFile("https://some.server/file.zip", filepath);
    }
    catch (Exception exp)
    {
        Response.Write(exp.ToString());
    }
}
```

### Server Error in '/WebSite1' Application.

The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

Source Error:

Line 80:             WebClient client = new WebClient();

Line 81:             client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain");

Line 82:             client.DownloadFile("https://some.server/file.zip", filepath);

Comment: Are you able to login using a browser and download the files?

Comment: i m able to login on the server and able to view a protected page within

Comment: but i m not able to download file. Each time i try to download file it returns me  (401) unauthorize error.

Comment: If you can't download it in a browser, there is no way WebClient will be able to help you download it.

Comment: I thing i am not making myself clear. I am able to download it in the browser, but i m not able to directly download the file from my application.

Comment: The request you use to download the zip, doesn't point towards your cookie container. Please supply the full error and the line it occurs on.

Comment: Any help Possibe...???
This question is still on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this class derived from WebClient. It will always pass the cookies with every request.

```
class WebClientWithCookies: WebClient
{
    private CookieContainer _container = new CookieContainer();

    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address) 
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = base.GetWebRequest(address) as HttpWebRequest; 

        if (request != null) 
        { 
            request.Method = "Post";
            request.CookieContainer = _container; 
        } 

        return request;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use this to make your WebRequests. Refer here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/195443/WebClient-Class-with-Cookies

Comment: First visit your login url, pass your post data. Once you are logged in, then use the `DownloadFile` method to download your file.

Comment: that is the problem i guess. I m able to login the server but when i try to create a new request to download the file it returns unauthorization exeption.

Comment: Even when you are using the `WebClientWithCookies` class?

Comment: Check the response of your first request to ensure you managed to login successfully.

Comment: Its not possible to see the page behind the login page if i m not successfully logged in. but in this case i m getting the content of the page behind login page. the only problem comes when i try to download the file by specifying the url. In the above code is the issue is because i m trying to create a new webrequest to download the file. might this be creating the problem???

Answer (score 0):

Try checking this libraries: http://www.rebex.net/default.aspx

Comment: i m sry.... i dont found this any helpful. anything that i could include in my code and work this out... i m sure there must be some way to do this. specially when i m able to access the protected page of the server... Why am I not able to get access of the files.