# Accessing the protected area of an asp.net website via a System.Net.WebClient

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, webclient

I have a website running asp.net 2.0 with url authentication. There is a protected region of the website that requires users to log in to gain access to protected files. Is it possible to do the same thing using a System.Net.WebClient object to download a file in the protected area?

If you try to manually type in the url to a protected file, resource, page, etc it forwards you to the login page. I also get the html for the login page inside of "protectedFile.zip" whenever I execute the code below.

```
public void test()
{
        try
        {
            using (var client = new CookieAwareWebClient())
            {
                //Not sure which name values to include, so I used what was in the post output in Firefox's firebug.
                var values = new NameValueCollection
            {
                { "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Login1$UserName", "testUsername" },
                { "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Login1$Password", "testPassword" }
            };
                retValue = client.UploadValues("www.test.com/login.aspx", values);
                //retValue contains the login page?
                Console.WriteLine(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(retValue));
                // If the previous call succeeded we now have a valid authentication cookie??
                client.DownloadFile("www.test.com/protected/protectedFile.zip", "protectedFile.zip");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(retValue));
        }
}

public class CookieAwareWebClient : WebClient
{
    public CookieAwareWebClient()
    {
        CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
    }
    public CookieContainer CookieContainer { get; private set; }

    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)base.GetWebRequest(address);
        request.CookieContainer = CookieContainer;
        return request;
    }
}
```

I have looked at the following related questions but none of them have a final solution that I can understand.

[asp.net Download files from protected server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11185317/asp-net-download-files-from-protected-server)

[How do I authenticate a WebClient request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1883655/how-do-i-authenticate-a-webclient-request?rq=1)

[C# WebClient Log onto Website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459501/c-sharp-webclient-log-onto-website?rq=1)

[WebClient accessing page with credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11118712/webclient-accessing-page-with-credentials)

[Can't login into asp.net website with WebClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13906771/cant-login-into-asp-net-website-with-webclient)

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to "spoof" an ASP.Net Web Forms `Postback`, you will run into issues that will prevent you from doing so. You have to deal with [`VIEWSTATE` and `EVENTVALIDATION`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163512.aspx#S3)

> The __EVENTVALIDATION hidden field is a security measure new to ASP.NET 2.0. The feature prevents unauthorized requests sent by potentially malicious users from the client. To **ensure that each and every postback and callback event originates from the expected user interface elements**, the page adds an extra layer of validation on events.

Comment: Ok, how do you use the viewstate and eventvalidation in my example code? I have tried several things but nothing seems to work correctly.

Comment: See the quoted section above - it pretty much says that you can't. I have never personally tried however, and logically, you could try and inspect all the activity between client and the site (using Fiddler perhaps) and mimic the entire http req/response exchange.

Comment: Ok thank you! I believe I have fixed the issue using what you have provided so I gave you the answer. (Sorry for the delay!)